# Rails ActiveRecord query with where clause including a bound of a Postgresql tsrange data type

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails model that has an attribute (named `when`) that is a tsrange data type (a stored range of two datetimes in a single column) and I would like to write a query that returns rows with a lower bound of the tsrange that are > now (so, events starting in the future).

Rails gives the helper methods `begin` and `end` that can be used on serialized objects but I would prefer to have the database handle this sorting (as opposed to ruby).   The ruby implementation is:

```
Event.select {|e| e.when.begin > Time.now}
```

The below SQL statement executes what I'm looking for but I can't figure out how to produce a similar result using ActiveRecord directly.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT events.* FROM events WHERE lower(events.when) >= NOW()")
```

I'm using

- Rails 4.0.1
- ruby-2.0.0-p247
- psql (9.2.4)

EDIT:

Here's one way that gets closer but still requires writing out SQL and embedding `now` into the sql as opposed to using a ruby object:

```
Event.where("lower(events.when) >= NOW()")
```

Comment: I don't think that there is something builtin. You can use [AREL](https://github.com/rails/arel) though.

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing like that in Rails for now. I would just like to point out that the `tsrange` data type is a range of dates, not datetimes. For datetimes, you should use `tsrange` or `tstzrange`. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html

Comment: Also, if all you really want is to use `Time.now`, then you can do `Event.where("lower(events.when) >= #{Time.now}")`.

Comment: I updated the title to say tsrange instead of daterange.  I got a syntax error using `Event.where("lower(events.when) >= #{Time.now}")` but did get it to work using `Event.where("lower(events.when) >= ?", Time.now)`